# bibtex fails with error: "document.blg: Forbidden to open for writing"

Tags: bibtex

I am using a Windows Vista system. From the command line,

```
pdflatex ...document
```

works fine, with the expected errors about missing citations. It also reports:

> No file document.bbl

which I assume is ok, because I think document.bbl is to be created by bibtex. However, when I run bibtex I get the error

> document.blg: Forbidden to open for writing I couldn't open file
>   ...document.blg

I thought bibtex created and wrote its own log file (.blg); so I am confused about how to proceed.

Comment: try running the executables as administrator. This is probably a windows security error. Right click on the file and use run as administrator.

Comment: Which TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I wouldn't adivse on running arbitrary programs as administrator. Especially not to one still running Vista. `,-)`

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend. I found these answers:

1. http://tex.aanhet.net/rugtex/trouble.html
2. http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2010-September/027229.html

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.  The first reference is for a package called TeXnicCenter, which apparently provides for "make-like" command line arguments for bibtex.  The second is for TexLive 2010, which is what I was using, but only the question is posted - no answer.  I do appreciate your effort to help someone who is still working at the "magic" level.

Comment: @Gene: Follow the links `next message` for the second reference. It brings you to http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2010-September/027234.html and http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2010-September/027246.html